# Symfony 3 controller design for web application and json REST API

Tags: symfony

I'm building a web application with Symfony 3 and I need a REST API for mobiles applications. I use FosUserBundle and FosRestBundle.

Here's a simple controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/titles/add", name="_addTitle");
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $title = new Title();
    $title->setUserId($this->getUser()->getId());

    $form = $this->createForm(NewTitle::class, $title);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->get('title.manager')->saveTitle($title);
        return $this->redirect('/contacts/add');
    }

    return $this->render('title/add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

/**
 * @Post("/api/titles")
 */
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $title = new Title();
    $title->setUserId(1);

    $form = $this->createForm(NewTitle::class, $title);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->get('title.manager')->saveTitle($title);
        return View::create($title, Codes::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    return View::create($form, Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I have one action for the web application and one action for REST API. Business logic is in a "manager" service.

NewTitle Form Type :

```
class NewTitle extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('label', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Add title'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
    }
}
```

My goal is to keep the code clean and avoid duplication. I have some questions :

- Do you see a better way ?
- in the postAction, when I have form errors it displays the "submit" field in my JSON response. How can I use same form class but "submit" element only for HTML form ?

Comment: [How to create an API style application base in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/cyxj/how-to-create-an-api-style-application-base-in-symfony)